# Pass a file stream from api to client through a middle api

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a export node.js REST API that makes a call to another REST API that send back a zip file.

The client side is a button that submit a form that call the export API, it should prompt user to download.

In the export API, I just do `res.send` but it render the stream content int he browser page.

Comment: the submit is a POST or an AjaxCall? The rest api is implemented with some framework?

Comment: A little bit more information would be nice... Are you using a framework like ExpressJS or Restify or maybe plain JS/NodeJS? Further please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or some snippet of code... Thanks